# How to show something when an image displays?

Tags: html, css, image

I want to check if an application is running on another server and the **only** way I can do this is by displaying an image that it provides.
If it doesn't provide the image, I use the alt attribute to inform that the app is down.
I cannot modify what's in the image, so I need a way to show something else that says that the app is up instead of saying "if you see this image it means that the app is up".

I'd like a CSS/HTML solution, if not, a JS or PHP one.

I'm thinking of hiding the image itself with the "the app is up" message but I don't know how. It doesn't work like image replacement usually do.

Comment: What exactly happens if the server is down? Does the image request fail? How exactly?

Comment: I just call it with an img tag, after that it's up to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose a custom message to display when the image is down using pure HTML and CSS, but for the image loading successfully, I think you're out of luck. Use a JavaScript Ajax request and check the returned status header, and you won't even have to create an image.